# CMake ExternalProject_Add with GNU autoconf

Tags: c++, cmake, mpg123

I'm trying to build a project using cmake, which uses the libmpg123 library. I read that I could use cmake's externalproject module to automatically download and configure external libraries, but libmpg123 doesn't use cmake, it uses autotools.
I'd like my directory structure to look like this

```
├── build
│  └── ...
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── libs
│  └── libmpg123
│     └── ...
│  └── <more libraries>
└── main.cpp
```

So whenever the user invokes make (after cmake), all libraries that I'm using are download into the `libs` folder. I only want the sources of my dependencies in the `libs` directory, not their object files, or anything else. That should go in the `build` directory when the user uses `make`.
Currently, my CMakeLists.txt looks like this

```
# minimum CMake version required
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)

project(proj VERSION 1.0 DESCRIPTION "desc")
set(CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS ON)
 
include(FetchContent)
include(ExternalProject)

ExternalProject_Add(libmpg123
    GIT_REPOSITORY          "https://github.com/gypified/libmpg123.git"
    GIT_TAG                 "master"
    GIT_SHALLOW             true
    UPDATE_DISCONNECTED     true

    SOURCE_DIR              "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/libmpg123-src"
    BINARY_DIR              "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/libmpg123-bin"

    CONFIGURE_COMMAND       "<SOURCE_DIR>/configure"
    BUILD_COMMAND           "${MAKE}"
    INSTALL_COMMAND         "echo" # Do nothing
)
add_library(mpg123 INTERFACE IMPORTED GLOBAL)

set(SOURCES
    main.cpp
)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SOURCES})
 
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}
    mpg123
)
add_dependencies(${PROJECT_NAME} libmpg123)
 
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE
    include
)
 

set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTIES
    CXX_STANDARD 17
    CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON
)
```

However, this isn't working. It invokes `autoconf` fine, but for some reason, skips the build step, saying `No build step for libmpg123`, and I also believe this isn't an acceptable way of achieving what I want.

What should I change about my project?

Comment: Use `execute_process` to build projects using non-CMake tools during Configure time.

Comment: "but for some reason, skips the build step, saying `No build step for libmpg123`" - This is because variable `MAKE`, which you used for `BUILD_COMMAND`, is **never defined**, thus its dereference returns the empty string.